# Use Parse Features with No Login in app

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

I would like to use some Parse features, but not require users to login.  For example, the app has a view with multiple buttons, when a button is pressed, it sends an update to a class in Parse which will increase a count by 1.  I just need very little with Parse, and would prefer to not have users signup for an account, or login with Facebook or Twitter just to accomplish a few small things.  Is it possible to just log them in automatically with a guest-style account (provided I let them know small actions are being stored on server, but no personal data at all is, and allow them to opt out?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the part in the parse.com documentation. They talk about anonymous users (you don't need a login).

[Parse.com Documentation about Anonymous Users](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-anonymous-users)

Comment: Awesome!  Navigating all their tutorials and information is a pain sometimes

Comment: @user717452 yeah it definitely can be for sure haha. Glad I could help out